# How can I install Internet connection to Ubuntu via USB-stick?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, internet

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 without ethernet or wifi. How can I install working internet connection to it via USB stick? I installed `net-tools` and `iwconfig` says `lo no wireless extension` and `enp2s0 no wireless extension`. My computer is Lenovo IdeaPad L340.

Comment: So you want to install a driver for your wifi card?

Comment: Yes. And for ethernet too. But wifi first.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is possible, but a bit annoying - i once did the same:

**1. Identify the card**

`lspci -nn` will return a list of devices incl. their verndor+device codes (`[1234:abcd]`). use this one to find the right driver. Download the respective `.deb` file, if your "download PC" has `apt`, it's as easy as

```
apt download driver-package-name
```

and you'll have the `driver.deb`-file in the current directory.

**2. Get your dependencies**

Use `dpkg -I driver.deb | grep Depends:` and check dependencies. Now on the target PC simply use `dpkg` to check if the dependent packages are installed:

```
dpkg -l package1 package2 ....
```

`ii` in the first column means installed, an error or e.g. `un` means not installed. [More on the `dpgk` codes here.](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/status-dpkg-list/)

Anything missing needs to be downloaded and checked for dependencies like in steps 1 & 2.

---

Usually a driver does not have that many dependencies and recursive dependencies, so the approach should be fine. However for a complete list of recursive dependencies, there is `apt-rdepends <package>` as separate program available. Just in case you need a FULL list of all dependencies and recursive dependencies of a package. I doubt it is necessary in this case.

---

**3. Install**

Install the `.deb` files via `dpkg -I dependency1.deb dependency2.deb driver.deb`

**4. Hint**

I think you can save a lot of time if you have a USB-Ethernet connector at hand. They should work out of the box on a Debian install and you could just directly connect the PC.

**5. Alternative approach to step 2.**

Instead of manually checking for dependencies, just try to install the `driver.deb` and get missing packages from the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Usually an update will install the wireless adapter driver.   I understand you'll need a working internet connection to update the OS.  So there is a chance you can connect to the internet using the existing enp2s0 adapter via ethernet cable.  Then apt-get upgrade.  That should do it.

Comment: I have a working connection on another computer so I was thinking if I can download a suitable deb-file from it and copy it to another computer by USB-stick and then install the driver.